# replacing all occurences of %3b in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

We find that customers with certain email providers get semi colons replaced with %3b, so the URL we send to them becomes

```
http://www.mytestsite.com/connect/vehicles/?rm=view_results%3bmake=BMW%3bmodel=3%20SERIES%3bvehicle_type_desc=Car
```

but it needs to be

```
http://www.mytestsite.com/connect/vehicles/?rm=view_results;make=BMW;model=3%20SERIES;vehicle_type_desc=Car
```

I have tried any number of configurations in the httpd.conf and .htaccess files to solve this problem without success. I have opted to use the .htacces file and here are some of my attempts in that file.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^?\ ]*)%253b([^?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1;%2 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule (.*)\%3b(.*)\%3b(.*)\%3b(.*) $1;$2;$3;$4 [R=301,L]
```

Also

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(%3b)(.*)
RewriteRule ^%3b %1;%2? [R=301,L,NC,NE
```

Any help detailing which file is best to use (httpd.conf or .htaccess) and how to achieve the goal would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue after a bit of trial and error. Below is the rewrite condition and rule.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^.]+view_results)%3b([^.]+)%3b([^.]+)%3b([^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.mytestsite.com/connect/vehicles/?rm=view_results;%2;%3;%4 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

From this solution, I confess that the original question was ill conceived and probably that's why I got no help here. The question should have been "How can I redirect this URL by replacing %3b?"

To explain the solution:

The RewriteCond obtains everything in the QUERY_STRING that's punctuated with 3 %3bs. Of course from the regex, one can see that we do not capture the offending characters as we will replace them subsequently and we make this capture case-insensitive ([NC]).

The RewriteRule takes everything in the whole URL and replaces it with the correct pattern, inserting the captures as %2, etc. We don't want %1, if we are interested in only one pattern of URL and are going to rewrite it anyway.

What to watch out for is that if the RewriteCond did not have the literal string "view_results", then it captures any URL that has this pattern AND some CGI requests constructed by our system matched this pattern.

Similarly using the wildcard ".*" to capture the URL in the RewriteRule is not ideal, but I found no way to make the RewriteRule recognise patterns from %1, etc., so the advice is to only use this method if you have ensured that your RewriteCond will prevent inadvertent behaviour.

Hope this helps someone else out there.